# Executing Shell script file from C#

Tags: c#, linux, shell

I have a shell script file in Fedora named **run.sh**. I would like to know when I execute this file from C# code will that file be executed as a root with superuser privileges ? As far as I understand we provide password and only then we are root user.

Method which executes the file run.sh is as below:

```
private String runCron()
{                       
    ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo ();
    ps.FileName = "/home/kc/test/run.sh";
    ps.UseShellExecute = false;
    ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    Process process = Process.Start (ps);
    process.WaitForExit ();
    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: you can run your C# script itself with superuser privileges

Comment: No I mean in my above mentioned code will it run with superuser privilege??

Comment: If you run your C# script as superuser then, run.sh would also run as superuser

Comment: I don't have a C# script I have a C# code which has above method to execute Shell script file. I open my browser and enter the url and on this action it executes the above method. I don't understand what do you mean by "execute C# script as administrator". Can you please eleborate??

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you run your C# process with root elevated privileges.
If you sudo your C# programm then you will run the following script with root privileges.
If you don't sudo, you have to be logged as root if you wish it to run with root privileges.
Or the script itself can ask for root privileges by executing a `sudo su` for example.